# Updating field sequentially while inserting data in SQL

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a scenario where in I want a field in a table to be incremented sequentially. 
Suppose I have a table Test, with columns TestID, TestResult1,2 etc.. and TestCount.
I have data bulk inserted into the table. Some of the records may be retests, which means new data to be inserted matches existing records in the table, Test Count should be updated.Matching is done on TestID

If the table is as follows:

```
TestID TestResult1 TestResult2.. TestCount 
12         1         1             1
12         2          2            2
13         4         1             1
```

Data to be inserted in

```
TestID TestResult1 TestResult2.. 
12         3         5             
12         2          2
```

The table should be updated as

```
TestID TestResult1 TestResult2.. TestCount 
12         1         1             1
12         2         2             2
13         4         1             1
12         3         5             3
12         2         2             4
```

I tried adding a trigger on the table to update the TestCount Counting the number of records that matches. But it was updating the table as follows

```
TestID TestResult1 TestResult2.. TestCount 
12         1         1             1
12         2         2             2
13         4         1             1
12         3         5             3
12         2         2             3

CREATE TRIGGER trgTestCount
on Test
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
Update  g
Set TestCount= (Select Count(*)+1  from Test g join INSERTED g1 where g.TestID=g1.TestID )
from Test g
```

This is a SSIS package and I use a dataflow task to load data from STg table to test table.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you identifying rows uniquely? Your code will update all rows with and not just the last two.

Comment: Yes, I realize that now. Is there another way I can accomplish the above scenario?

Comment: I think the best way will be to calculate while you are actually inserting the data into the test table - Something like this:
`INSERT test (TestID, TestCount)
SELECT TestID, (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(TestCount),0) + 1 FROM Test WHERE TestID = StagingTable.TestID) AS TestCount
FROM StagingTable
`

Comment: This is a SSIS package and I use a dataflow task to copy from stg table to test table.

Comment: If the staging table and test table are on the same database or on the same server but different databases then you can do this in a stored procedure rather than a data flow task.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the table structure, I would suggest adding an [`Identity`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx) column, change the `TestCount` column to a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx#TsqlProcedure), and have it's value as the count of distinct test ids that are the same is the current row test id and the create date is lower than the current value of the `Identity` column.

This will eliminate the need for triggers and will handle inserting multiple records with the same test id automatically.

Comment: Can't be a direct computed column since you're trying to compute something about *other* rows in the table. Some people would use a UDF but I'd usually prefer to put the computation into a column of a view.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever good point. why would you prefer to compute the column in a view rather then using a computed column based on a UDF?

Comment: Mostly, irrational hatred of UDFs :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Actually, I can totally relate to that :-)